Update Claims from Another Application, Update Cookie Claims
The following are 2 endpoints in my controller, goal here is to pass a list of roles, and add them to the current cookie authenticated user as claims. It is worth noting this API uses both AddNegotiate and AddCookie as authentication methods.
[HttpPost("updateroles")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateRoles([FromBody] RoleUpdateRequest request)
{
    if (request.Roles == null)
    {
        return BadRequest("Roles cannot be null");
    }
    var currentClaimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity!;
    if (currentClaimsIdentity != null)
    {
        try
        {
            var claims = request.Roles!.Select(role => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role)).ToList();
            currentClaimsIdentity.AddClaims(claims);

            var newPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(currentClaimsIdentity);

            var lastAuthenticated = DateTime.UtcNow;

            var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties()
            {
                IsPersistent = true,
                ExpiresUtc = lastAuthenticated.AddHours(_appConfiguration.CookieTimeout)
            };

            var claimsMessage = string.Join(", ", newPrincipal.Claims.Select(c => c.Value));
            _logger.LogMessage("Updating User with Following Claims : " + claimsMessage);

            // Sign in with the new principal
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, newPrincipal, authProperties);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Role Update Error", ex);
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "An error occurred while updating roles.");
        }

        return Ok(new { Message = "Roles updated successfully", Roles = request.Roles });
    }

    return BadRequest("Unable to update roles.");
}

  [HttpGet("claims")]
  [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
  public async Task<IActionResult> GetClaims()
  {
      if (User.Identity!.IsAuthenticated)
      {
          var userId = User.Identity!.Name;
          return Ok(User.Claims.Select(c => new { c.Type, c.Value }));
      }

      return Unauthorized();
  }


Here is my authentication configuration in my dependency injection:
 // Cookies stored key ring
 services.AddDataProtection()
         .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(PHYSICALPATH))
         .SetApplicationName(config["CookieName"]!);

 services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
         .AddNegotiate() // For Windows Authentication to retrieve User Groups
         .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
         {
             options.Cookie.Name = config["CookieName"];
             options.Cookie.Domain = config["DomainSite"];
             options.Cookie.Path = "/";
             options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
             options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
             options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
         });

If I check the claims endpoint before and after the SignIn, it remains the same and wont show new claims.
What am I doing wrong here, or what could I do differently? Goal here is another application on the domain will send a list of new roles, apply to user, and have that show in the claims for this user after new Sign In.
Edit : Added login method client applications use.
 [AllowAnonymous]
 [HttpGet("login")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl)
 {
     if (User.Identity != null && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
     {
         var username = User.Identity.Name;
         var lastAuthenticated = DateTime.UtcNow;
         var roles = _domainUserGroupService.GetRolesFromGroups(User);

         // Create claims with the Claim Name from Identity Name as well as adding roles and Last Authenticated Timestamp
         var claims = _domainUserGroupService.CreateClaims(User.Identity.Name!, roles, lastAuthenticated);
         var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
         var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

         var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties()
         {
             IsPersistent = true,
             ExpiresUtc = lastAuthenticated.AddHours(_appConfiguration.CookieTimeout)
         };

         await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
         await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, authProperties);

         _logger.LogMessage("Login User Identity Name : " + username);



         return Redirect(returnUrl);
     }
     else
     {
         return Unauthorized();
     }
 }


Hi @Wolfenstyne, can you also pls share how do you sign in with cookie authentication?

@Rena , sure I went and added the login endpoint. Client applications get routed here, login the cookie, then get sent back to their return URL. Goal is to allow those same applications to update roles on the updateroles endpoint, and see the new claims reflect after.

Hi @Wolfenstyne, i have tested your code and it can add the new claims together with the existing claims. Do you want to update the existing claims with new value?

@Rena When I run this application and check claims, it has 3 claims. Then while it is open, I reach the update claims from application #2 (sharing this cookie) adding a 4th claim. However then when i re-run claims from this application it is not showing that claim on the User.Identity.Claims once application #2 has run updateroles. When claims are added to the user, should it not reflect for each application using the cookie to see new claims? Or am I not thinking correctly about how claims are updated to each application? This cookie is shared with the AddDataProtection.
